# Moving Spring WS Stomp server from SimpleBroker to RabbitMQ StompBrokerRelay

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, spring-ws

I have a Spring web app with Stomp WS, Spring v. 6.0.9, Windows environment, Tomcat 10.1, JRE 17, I'm currently using SimpleBroker but I need to clusterize the server and then I have to move to an external AMQP server, I deced to use RabbitMQ and Spring StompBrokerRelay.

This is the steps I did:

**1) Change the MessageBroker config to StompBrokerRelay**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/topic");
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
        .setRelayHost("localhost")
        .setRelayPort(61613)
        .setClientLogin("guest")
        .setClientPasscode("guest")
        .setAutoStartup(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/myws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }
}
```

**2) Install RabbitMQ and Stomp plugin**

I'm sure it is listening because I found this ports on rabbitmq management page:

[image]

**3) Finally I tried to run server and client**

The js client code was not changed from previous simplebroker version.

Server side I see this logs:

```
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.499 [clientOutboundChannel-11] NativeWebSocketSession - Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=113fcf11-773c-8eaf-8fb9-eec01b0204f3, uri=ws://127.0.0.1:8080/myws]
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.500 [clientOutboundChannel-11] LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - StandardWebSocketSession[id=113fcf11-773c-8eaf-8fb9-eec01b0204f3, uri=ws://127.0.0.1:8080/myws] closed with CloseStatus[code=1002, reason=null]
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.500 [clientOutboundChannel-11] SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - Clearing session 113fcf11-773c-8eaf-8fb9-eec01b0204f3
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.501 [clientOutboundChannel-12] SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - No session for GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=OTHER, stompCommand=ERROR, nativeHeaders={message=[Broker not available.]}, simpSessionId=113fcf11-773c-8eaf-8fb9-eec01b0204f3}]
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.501 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DispatcherServlet - GET "/myws", parameters={}
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.502 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WebSocketHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler@16e9324
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.502 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WebSocketHttpRequestHandler - GET /myws
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.503 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DispatcherServlet - Completed 101 SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS
[DEBUG] 2023-05-30 12:41:50.504 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - New StandardWebSocketSession[id=4d7e4bd4-e3dc-031f-177a-55a13fc27b2b, uri=ws://127.0.0.1:8080/myws]
```

In the client log I see HTTP 101 request with this response:

[image]

In rabbitMQ management I don't see any connection.

[image]

An interesting tip I got from StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler logs, is that the "system" connection to Rabbit seems to continously be opened and closed.

```
2023-06-01 15:02:36.156 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-2] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:36.190 TRACE 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-2] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:36.235 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-3] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:36.235 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-3] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:40.654 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-5] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:40.657 TRACE 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-5] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:40.667 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-6] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:40.667 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-6] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:41.248 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-8] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:41.250 TRACE 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-8] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:41.255 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-9] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:41.255 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-9] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:45.690 DEBUG 15784 --- [nt-scheduler-11] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:45.694 TRACE 15784 --- [nt-scheduler-11] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:45.706 DEBUG 15784 --- [nt-scheduler-12] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:45.706 DEBUG 15784 --- [nt-scheduler-12] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:46.262 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-2] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:46.263 TRACE 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-2] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:46.268 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-3] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:46.269 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-3] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:50.711 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-5] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:50.711 TRACE 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-5] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:50.716 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-6] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:50.717 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-6] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:51.273 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-8] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2023-06-01 15:02:51.274 TRACE 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-8] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECT, headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], passcode=[PROTECTED], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}
2023-06-01 15:02:51.278 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-9] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2023-06-01 15:02:51.279 DEBUG 15784 --- [ent-scheduler-9] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
```

To be sure this is not something related to my application, I also checked out this demo project: https://github.com/djselzlein/spring-websockets-rabbitmq-demo/
But it has the same problem.

Can you help to understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fresh, updated, installation of RabbitMQ on windows has solved my issue.
It was not related to Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned the demo project and started RabbitMQ with Docker and encountered the same problem. I had to activate the [STOMP plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html) from RabbitMQ. The STOMP adapter then listens on all interfaces on port 61613.

You can enable it with `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp`

I have used following Dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:latest

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp

EXPOSE 15671 15672 61613
```

I tried it again and the error was gone, I hope this is the case for you as well.

Comment: Hi DEvDan, thanks for your help. I'm not using docker, but the plugin is enabled. Please have a look at pt 2) of my question, Rabbitm management shows that the stomp ports is listening.

Comment: Your spring application can't get a connection to rabbitmq, did you check on OS level that the stomp plugin is listening? Can you check it with `netstat -an`? I suspect something is wrong with your erlang/rabbitmq setup. Did you install Erlang as a user and not as an admin maybe?

Comment: netstat shows that 61613 is listening and I could connect using `telnet localhost 61613`. I tried also to install the http-stomp plugin and connect directly from js, and it worked.

Comment: So it looks like everything is configured and setup correctly. It seems like something is interrupting or blocking the connection from your spring app to rabbitmq. It could not work because of a firewall or antivirus software or the like, have you ruled that out yet?

Comment: After a bit of pain I could start docker rabbitmq on windows and the demo project works for me too. So the issue is surely related to RabbitMq installation on Windows (I mean a plain rabbitmq installation without docker). 
I exclude it can be related to firewall or antivirus. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it works for you now. I can only recommend Docker to you, it makes setting up and trying out projects much easier and above all more comprehensible. At the same time, you don't have to worry so much about cleaning up.